# Deleting nested hash elements based on those elements' properties

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have some data:

```
data = {
"total_records"=>3,
"records"=>
   [{"title"=>"Val1",
   "coins"=>1},
   {"title"=>"Val2",
   "coins"=>1},
   {"title"=>"Val3",
   "coins"=>1}]
}
```

How would I go about deleting the records that have `title = 'Val1'||'Val2'`?

I tried something along these lines:

```
@data.records.each_value do |e|
    if exceptions.include?(e.title)
      delete @envelopes.records.e
    end
  end
```

But I get a no method error on `@data.records`.

Comment: "wasn't having it" is not a valid problem description. Also the code that was not having is not shown.

Comment: It was a no method error when I called it on the hash

Comment: A no method error was raised when it ("some message") was *sent to nil*. Which is a very basic mistake - there was nothing (nil) when something was expected. In this case it is likely that `@data` is nil - was it assigned/loaded?

Comment: Yes, I just wasn't accessing the object's children properly. See below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So simple

```
data['records'].delete_if{ |h| %w(Val1 Val2).include?(h['title']) }
```

Comment: Define an array outside the `delete_if` block that contains the values to be removed: `vals = %w(Val1 Val2); data['records'].delete_if{ |h| vals.include?(h['title']) }`. That runs about 10% faster with just two entries and will run even faster as `data['records']` or `vals` grow in size. As is, the array has to be redefined every time `delete_if` loops which wastes CPU.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing, I had my exception array that I matched against.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this:

```
data['records'].delete_if{ |h| (h['title'] == 'Val1') || (h['title'] == 'Val2') }
```